# What does the nodetool status note about replication settings actually mean?

Tags: cassandra

Recently I've seen the following message displayed by nodetool status:

```
Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

I was wondering what it means and whether it indicates any kind of problem.

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is no problem. It just means that you can't trust the owns column. This is because two (or more) of your keyspaces have different replication factor and it makes it hard to properly calculate how many tokens each node owns.